# Android Long Press on Edit Text behavior

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

Is it possible to add something to the list of items that shows up when a user long presses on any Edit Text? (Cut, copy paste, select text, select all, input method) I want to add an option to this that will scan a QR code and paste the result into the Edit Text. I think this would not be very hard to get this behavior out of Edit Texts that I put into my own application, but I am wanting to add this option to any Edit Text inside any application on my phone. Is something like this possible, if so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit 150 bounty: I am looking to add an item to the EditText pop-up dialog when it is long pressed. I want am looking for a way to make this change system wide, not just within the context of 1 application.

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this system wide?  I am trying to figure out how to do it with little success.

Comment: Nope, never came across a way. Best idea I had was create a keyboard replacement app that could have a scan button on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thats not possible, as the context menu is populated by applications themselves and not by the system. You cannot force other apps to have a context item that they might not use in their lifetime. You can atleast have the feature in apps that are aware of your app. 
Create an activity that populates and handles only your global menu items. Other apps can use the feature by extending your activity. But this too will create problems, as the other apps will have a hard dependency on your app. So if your app is not installed in that system then the other app won't work. Also there is no way to indicate of this dependency in the manifest file so that the dependent app is hidden in the market if your app is not already installed.

I'm sure this is not the answer you were looking for, but context menus are made so by design.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways: 1st one described by Shahab. 2nd one is more simple. You need to just override standard method of your activity, like:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
       if(view.getId()==R.id.MyEditTextId)
       {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, MyMenu, Menu.NONE, R.string.MyMenuText);
       }
       else
          super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
}
```

After that you'll have on long press popup context menu

Comment: I think this is closer to what I am looking for. But I am not looking to make this work within one of my applications. I want it to be system wide whenever I long press on any Edit Text within any application I want to add an option to the menu that pops up. Is it possible to do something like this system wide?

Comment: Thats not possible, as the context menu is populated by the applications themselves and not by the system. You cannot force other apps to have a context item that they might not need. You can atleast have the feature in apps that are aware of your app. create a library with an activity that populates your menu items. Other apps can use the feature by extending your activity.

Comment: @userSeven7s: I would argue. If you will have one root Activity which is parent for all application's activities - you can override onCreatContextMenu in a way I have described above - so whenever user long press there will be context menu, huh?

Comment: @barmaley: Sorry, the comment was in reply to Tim's. I know now I should have added the '@Tim' before comment. I have also added the cmment as answer. that proves it was not for your answer. Nothing wrong in your answer. It works well for context menu within individual apps.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to add something to the list of items on LongClick of EditText.

To put you in right direction I am posting some code snippets.

In main.xml do something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<EditText  
              android:id="@+id/textt"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:text="@string/hello"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

After that in your main Activity, do something like

```
public class edit extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText text = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.textt);
    text.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            //ADD HERE ABOUT CUT COPY PASTE  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Hope it helps