# Background App to scan into active textbox?

Tags: android, iphone, smartphone

I was looking for an app for phones (iPhone, Android and SmartPhone - any or all) that would simply run in the background and place any scanned upc code digits into the currently active textbox.

I've Googled for quite a while and only found an Android app that actually replaces the keyboard of the phone.

It seems like it should be easy (I have many for PCs) but I haven't done any handheld programming since Windows CE days so I don't know if this is possible (can apps see other apps controls in these phones).

Has anyone ever come across an app like this?

Comment: you can definitely show a TextView from background..

Comment: What I'm hoping for is a way to scan a upc into the textbox of a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the iphone sdk from zbar and you can do it inside your app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this system wide. You can only add this functionality to your apps.

This question is very similar Take a look. [Android Long Press on Edit Text behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181309/857361)

Comment: FWIW; You can't do this in iOS either

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. Perhaps there are similar keypad replacement apps for iPhone and SmartPhone that will allow me to shell a browser in them and scan into it. Thank you.